# HTML CSS Print page removing whitespace at top and bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to print an HTML page and I'm having a hard time getting rid of extra white space at the top and bottom of the page.

Here's what the print preview looks like (arrows pointing to the space):

[image]

and my CSS:

```
@@media print {
        body {
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .body.menubar-top {
            padding-top: 0px;
        }

        .no-print {
            display: none;
        }

        #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
            visibility: visible;
            margin-top: 0px;
            padding-top: 0px;
        }

        #section-to-print {
            /*position: absolute;*/
            /*left: 0;
            top: 0;*/
        }
    }
```

and the page code:

```
    <div class="row" id="section-to-print" style="vertical-align:top">

    <div class="col-md" id="projectDetails">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="headerTitle">
                Main Title
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4 class="headerTitle">
                Sub title
            </h4>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h5>
                    Project Details
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>

etc......
```

I haven't created a print page in a while but I'm sure this should be simple.

Comment: Hi @TrevorGoodchild! Interesing question. Could you confirm that your `media print` styles are working corectly? I'm surprised with `@@` at the beginning

Comment: Hi kade, yes they are working.  I'm doing this in a razor template so I need to use the double @@s

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks completly valid. I made JSFiddle with your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/a6fu1vcg/2/

For example if you have for example in code:

```
body {
  margin: 200px;
}
```

When you try to print it it will be override:

```
@media print {
        body {
            margin: 5px;
        }
}
```

And printing document will have 5px body margin.

Be sure that you don't have any other styles for example with `!important` that overrides your printing styles